# Binomial Min Heap delete issue

Tags: binomial-heap

[image: Quiz Question]

Got this problem on a recent CS class quiz that I got wrong. These were the choices:

- 3,4
- 10,13
- 10, 9
- 10

I put 10 and am pretty sure I am right. Can someone explain why I am not?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but here's how it should work:

- Remove 1 creating new heaps 2->10 and 9 (orders 1 and 0).
- Merge these with the rest of the heap.
- 2->10 stays as-is. There's no other order 1 heap (for now).
- Merge 9 and 13 into 9->13.
- Now merge 9->13 and 2->10 to get a new order 2 heap.

```
   2->10
    -> 9->13
```

- There's no other order 2 heap, so we're done.

So the children of 2 are 9,10.